# Food expiration database

Tags: data-request

I was wondering if there are any open sources/databases for which I can find standard food lifespans/expirations? This would possibly include shelf life estimations for raw/uncooked, refrigerated, cooked, or frozen food.

I've tried looking through the [USDA](https://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=8964) and [Open Food Facts](http://world.openfoodfacts.org/data) but couldn't find any expiration-related data.

If anyone has any suggestions of where I can find this information (or if they know of a collection of sites that offer this info that I can scrape from) I'd love to hear it. If I end up needing to scrape the data from somewhere I'd be happy to release it back to the community.

Comment: The only one that I know of has a TOS against copying : StillTasty.com

Comment: Nachoes are delicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a link to the Food Bank of Alabama, which has a 26 page PDF with a table of food expiration dates ([pdf link](http://foodbankofeastalabama.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Just-How-Long-Is-That-Food-Good.pdf)). Here is [another similar PDF](http://lee.ces.ncsu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/TheFoodKeeper.pdf), but even less machine readable. And here is [yet another one (PDF)](http://www2.ca.uky.edu/hes/fcs/factshts/FN-SSB.085.PDF).

[image]

It's not too machine readable, but you may be able to copy individual pages and paste them into a spreadsheet tool.

If this data source is useful for you, I can also help get it to be machine readable using a tool like [pdftotext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext).